# How do I add a row to mySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add an "admin" section of my website. Right now I am working on a section to add a new row to my MySQL database.

The first file is my admin.php:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="order" />
    <input type="text" name="newstatus" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My goal here is to add 2 pieces of data (the table only has 2 columns right now) to the new row.

Then, I have my add.php file:

```
<?
//declare my connection variables - I'll move these to a secure method later
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

// The SQL statement is built

$sql="INSERT INTO $tblname(id, status)VALUES('$order', '$newstatus')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
    echo mysqli_errno($this->db_link);
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Anytime i input any data (non-duplicate of what is already in the table), it gives me an error. If I clear my table completely of all data, it will input once. I am getting a duplicate key error, but my key should be "orders", which is unique every time I input it.

Suggestions?

Comment: suggest dropping mysql_* functions and switching to pdo, and using prepared statements. if you're interested in finding out why, search for 'sql injection'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are actually inserting a new row, you shouldn't fill the ID yourself but rather set it as `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your database. And then, have you form as such:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="newstatus" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

And your PHP code like so:

```
$newstatus = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newstatus']); // note the usage of $_POST variable
$sql="INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (`status`) VALUES ('$newstatus')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Failed executing query: '.mysql_error());
```

`AUTO_INCREMENT` can be set up in `phpMyAdmin` with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `WorkOrders` MODIFY `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Finally, don't use `mysql_*` functions, [they are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/jpegchaos/public_html/add.php on line 27

Comment: new line - updated above. was trying to get it to display the error on my .php

Comment: Do **not** switch from MySQL to MySQLi. Those two resources are not compatible with each other. And what does `$this->db_link;` refer to?

Comment: it's my 'if it doesn't update, do this [else]" section. I'm grabbing code off of tutorials to try and display the error - obviously the wrong code to use.. I'm searching for better code unless you have something.

Comment: I've added a third line in the PHP code in my answer. Do as indicated to retreive MySQL errors.

Comment: with update: Failed executing query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(status) VALUES('2')' at line 1     /////  I input "2" for that variable in the form.

Comment: Failed executing query: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' // I did not input "0" - I used "47"

Comment: Then, set your field as `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your database using phpMyAdmin as per what I said in my answer.

Comment: and we have a winner.. My box for it was marked, but it must have had a very low value set. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the 'id' field of your table is a primary key. If that's the case, you cannot have two rows that have the same identifier.

By your variable name *newstatus*, it seems to me like you're trying to update the status of an order ; is it the case? If yes, you should use a UPDATE SQL query of the form:

```
UPDATE table SET status='somestatus' WHERE id=someid
```

Comment: I had to update my notes a little. "id" was "orders" - "orders" is my primary key - and I am never duplicating my inputs... IE: 1 is used, I use 2 etc.    I am attempting to add a new row, not update an existing one.

Comment: Can you print $sql before executing it, to make sure the SQL query is what you expect?

Comment: when I echo the form data, they come out as I requested. They are not duplicates of the existing data

Comment: Whats your table name and databse name? atleast table name

Comment: $dbname = "RepairStatus";
    $tblname = "WorkOrders";